# Get URL of clicked link inside of UIWebView use Swift 2

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, swift2, uitextfield

I have UITextField and UIWebView like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Z9Z.png)

But when I clicked a link inside webview, the textfield above did not change to clicked URL.

I try with :

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let scheme = request.URL!
    print(scheme)
}
```

and this:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .LinkClicked {
        print(request.URL.path)
    }
    return true
}
```

and this:

```
textfield.text = webview.request.URL.absoluteString
```

but it did not get request.URL.path and webview.request.URL.absoluteString.

How to make texfield.text change to clicked URL from webview?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 8 and later, use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView):

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript.

The minor annoyance is that `WKWebView` can be dragged and dropped via Interface Builder so you have to add it to your view in code. Here's the navigation part:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.addressField.text = webView.URL!.absoluteString
}
```

Comment: the problem is I use storyboard not programmatically